# In Pages 5.1 how can I add "Chapter"or "§" to the numbering of a heading?

Tags: pages

I have imported a Word document into Pages 5.1

Instead of text+number heading styles like "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", I only see numbers as available choices.

Can I customize the styles so as to add words or symbols to numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Are you referring to Paragraph Styles such as [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6TNJG.png) or something else? Also, what operating system and version of pages are you using? (iOS or Mac or iCloud web interface, etc...)

Comment: Yes, I am referring exactly to Paragraph Styles. I am using a Mac with OS X Mavericks. As a matter of fact, I have compiled a rather long MS Word document with numbered chapters and paragraphs (like "Assignment 1. Do this", "Assignment 2. Do that", where the numbering was part of the paragraph style, and you could add any word or symbol to the number in the style definition. Now, I am trying to use Pages to lay the text out for print. (MS Word is no good for that.) Everything converts OK except those words "Chapter", "Assignment" and symbols accompanying the numbers ("§10"). Can I add them?